# Summarize: New column using values from different vector

Tags: r, summarize

(Rewrite. Very new to R, sorry if my jargon is off below!)

Goal: Summarize values in a dataset, create a column with a total of values selected in the summary, then create an average based on that total against the total in the original, summarized dataset.

*Desired Output: nonStandardActivationsSummary*
year    subCount    institutions    percentOfAllInYear
2017    2           1               .33
2018    1           1               .33

*Starting data: fullData*
pid     startDate   subLength
4484    2017-01-30  365
4487    2017-01-01  25
4487    2017-07-01  360
6246    2018-04-29  345
4485    2018-02-01  30
4486    2018-07-01  730

*What I'm trying*
1. Create vector that filters all but non-standard subscription lengths (works)

```
nonStandardActivations <- filter(fullData, !is.na(subLength) & subLength != 30 & (subLength%%365) != 0)
```

*Result: nonStandardActivations (good so far)*
pid     startDate   subLength
4487    2017-01-01  25
4487    2017-07-01  360
6246    2018-04-29  345

2. Create summary of the nonstandard subscriptions, with an added column that gives number of non-standard in a year as % of total in original dataset, for that year only. (doesn't work)

```
nonStandardActivationsSummary <- summarize(
  group_by(nonStandardActivations, year = format(startDate,'%Y')), 
    subCount = n(), 
    institutions=length(unique(pid)), 
    percentOfAllInYear = (length(unique(pid))  / 
                          length(unique(filter(fullData, 
             format(startDate, '%Y'))$pid))))
```

The above gives me: "Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector". If I remove the percentOfAllInYear clause, it works fine but I don't get that last column.

I suspect I have a totally off approach. Or am lost in how vectors get used in a function chain. Help?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Rewrote. Hopefully better?